# Recursive Knapsack in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, knapsack-problem

I have read many variations of the Knapsack problem, but the version I am tasked with is a little different and I don't quite understand how to solve it.

I have an array of integers that represent weights (ie. {1,4,6,12,7,2}) and need to find only one solution that adds up to the target weight.

I understand the basic algorithm, but I cannot understand how to implement it.

First, what is my base case? Is it when the array is empty? The target has been reached? The target has been over-reached? Or maybe some combination?

Second, when the target is over-reached, how do I backtrack and try the next item?

Third, what am I supposed to return? Should I be returning ints (in which case, am I supposed to print them out?)? Or do I return arrays and the final return is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Think carefully about the problem you are trying to solve. To approach this problem, I am
considering the inputs and outputs of the Knapsack algorithm.

**Input:** A set of integers (the knapsack) and a single integer (the proposed sum)

**Output:** A set of integers who add up to the proposed sum, or null.

In this way your code might look like this

```
public int[] knapsackSolve(int[] sack, int prospectiveSum) {
    //your algorithm here
}
```

The recursive algorithm is straightforward. First compute the sum of the sack. If it equals
prospectiveSum then return the sack. Otherwise iterate over sack, and for each item initialise a new knapsack with that item removed. Call knapsackSolve on this. If there is a solution, return it. Otherwise proceed to the next item.

For example if we call knapsackSolve({1,2,3},5) the algorithm tries 1 + 2 + 3 = 5 which is false. So it loops through {1,2,3} and calls knapsackSolve on the sublists {2,3},{1,3} and {1,2}. knapsackSolve({2,3},5) is the one that returns a solution.

This isn't a very efficient algorithm although it illustrates fairly well how complex the Knapsack problem is!

Comment: You say the output is a **set of integers**, but I only see `int` in your sample code

Comment: In terms of the problem, the output is a set of integers. In terms of the solution (implementation), the output is `int[]`. So I didn't mean set of integers in the `Set<Integer>` sense. It would be a good idea to use `Set<Integer>` for this solution but I thought arrays would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Knapsack problem is formulated as (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)): "Given a set of items, each with a mass and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible. For your problem we are interested in weights only. So you can set all values to 1. Additionally we only want to know if the target weight can be reached exactly. I guess you are allowed to use a weight only once and not multiple times?
This problem can be solved nicely with dynamic programming. Are you familiar with that principle? Applying dynamic programming is much more elegant and quicker to program than backtracking. But if you are only allowed to do backtracking use the approach from user2738608 posted above.